# Search directories listed in the PATH environment variable

Tags: windows, path, find

I am trying to find and remove any instance of a .dll that appears in any directory that's on the PATH environment variable in windows.

Is there an easy way to do this from the CMD window?

Comment: The reason you can't use Windows Search is because?

Comment: Is there a way to make Windows Search search in a set of directories, like in the PATH environment variable? I know how to make it search in a subdirectory. But I don't want to manually cut and paste each directory from PATH and do a search there.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve besides trying to locate files in specific directories?

Comment: What do you mean by instances of a dll..  Given one particular file, you can't have more than one instance of it in a directory. Perhaps you mean how many dll files there are in the directory? Or do you just mean which directories have that one particular file?

Comment: Yes Barlop - I mean to find each directory which contains a particular file. The use case is that I am trying to find and remove any duplicates of 'cygwin1.dll' that are in %PATH%.

Comment: Be careful with removing any duplicates of a particular `dll` based on name only. Could  be another version (32 or 64 bit); could be referenced by a hard-coded path (e.g. by starting directory) in calling app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WHERE command](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html):

> Locate and display files in a directory tree.
>
> The `WHERE` command is roughly equivalent to the UNIX '`which`'
>   command. By default, the search is done in the current directory and
>   in the `PATH`.

You could use

```
where anyname.dll
```